# Chrome, setting width/height in rem units with jQuery do not work as expected

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, responsive-design, width

I am building a responsive div grid (like a regular mosaic) grouped by floating (div) columns.
I need to calculate and set the width of each column in rem units and so I do with this simple jQuery instruction:

```
$column.css("width", col_width+"rem");
```

My root font-size is 2vh.
On Firefox and Explorer the new width is handled correclty, as it is actually set in declarative mode (i.e. column width is responsive), but on Chrome the width seems to be computed and column width turns fixed, not being responsive as I change viewport height.
Is it a known problem? Is there a solution to make Chrome accepting rem units on setting without computing?

Thank you

Comment: We need to see more code. Why don't you set this up in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I didn't want to put in too much confusing code. Anyway, I followed your suggestion and I set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofufaxvf/1/).
What is really weird is that the extracted code works properly on Chrome too! While inside my code it shows the mentioned issue. Anyway I found a working solution: setting the container width in rem and the columns width in percentual (100/n_col+'%'). But it still really weird that if I set the column width in rem and leave the container width as it is (i.e. non defined, width auto-adjusts to its content) my code is not working on Chrome.

Comment: I am a bit confused as the behaviour looks the same to me on Chrome and FF. I am running a mac on Yosemite. Chrome 40.0.2214.111 and FF 35.0